# Encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am running the docker image from Jenkinsfile, the docker command in jenkinsfile is as following command -

```
> docker run --name "Test_Windows_Name" -v
> C:\Jenkins\workspace\Test_Windows:"C:\workspace" -t
> xyz/windows/dependencycheckwindows:latest -projectName "DotNet_2017"
> -projectRoot "C:\workspace\Web\DotNet_2017\WebApplication1" -jobName "Test_Windows_Job" -buildNumber "16"

While running the Jenkinsfile, I am getting below error -

> docker: Error response from daemon: container
> 250fa4616cf0695b9ece7603cdf28e062ifad23eb7f4abc6da63a0f6796802d2
> encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in
> a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified.
> (0x2) extra info: {"CommandLine":"python run_windows.py -projectName
> DotNet_2017 -projectRoot
> C:\\workspace\\Web\\DotNet_2017\\WebApplication1 -jobName
> Test_Windows_Job -buildNumber
> 16","WorkingDirectory":"C:\\pythonapp","EmulateConsole":true,"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0]}.

Please help in resolving the issue.

Here is the dockerfile code -
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
    RUN SETX version_url "https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/current.txt"
    RUN SETX download_url "https://dl.bintray.com/jeremy-long/owasp"
    RUN mkdir C:\staging
    RUN echo %version_url% > C:\staging\version.txt
    RUN powershell.exe -c "invoke-webrequest 'https://jeremylong.github.io/DependencyCheck/current.txt' -O C:\staging\current.txt"
    RUN SETX file "dependency-check-%current.txt%-release.zip"
    RUN echo %file% > C:\staging\file.txt
    RUN SETX url "%download_url% + '/' + %file%"
    RUN echo %url% > C:\staging\url.txt
    WORKDIR C:\\staging
    ENTRYPOINT ["CMD"]
```

Here is the JenkinsFile code -

> ```
> > pipeline {
> >         agent { label 'windows' }
> >         environment {
> >           docker_repo = 'xyz.compute.amazonaws.com:8083'
> >     
> >             docker_image = "${docker_repo}/xyz/sast/windows/dependencycheckwindows:latest"
> >          }
> >     
> >            stages {
> >             stage('Setup') {
> >                 steps {
> >                   withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'id',
> ```
>
> usernameVariable: 'user', passwordVariable: 'password')]){
>
> > ```
> >                 bat 'echo "Connecting with Git repository"'
> >                 bat 'git config --global credential.helper cache'
> >                 bat 'git config --global user.email "${user}@dummy.com"'
> >                 bat 'git config --global user.name "${user}"'
> >               }
> >               withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'Repo_id',
> > ```
> >
> > usernameVariable: 'Repo_user', passwordVariable:
> >     'Repo_password')]){
> >                        bat 'echo "Connecting with Nexus repository"'
> >                        bat "docker login --username=${Repo_user} --password=${Repo_password} ${env.docker_repo}"
> >                       }
> >                     }
> >                 }
> >                 stage('Run OWASP Dependency Check scan') {
> >                 steps {
> >                   bat '''
> >                   echo "Starting Docker Image"
> >                          docker pull %docker_image%
> >                          docker run --name "%JOB_NAME%" -v %workspace%:"C:\workspace" -t %docker_image% -projectName
> >     "DotNet_2017" -projectRoot
> >     "C:\workspace\Web\DotNet_2017\WebApplication1" -jobName
> >     "%JOB_NAME%" -buildNumber "%BUILD_NUMBER%"
> >                          '''
> >                    }
> >                 }
> >             }
> >             post {
> >                 always {
> >                     archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'artifacts\*.log', fingerprint: true
> >                     bat '''
> >                            echo 'Cleaning up the environment.'
> >                            docker stop -t 0 "%JOB_NAME%"
> >                            docker rm "%JOB_NAME%"
> >                            docker rmi %docker_image%
> >                            docker system prune -f
> >                            set reportfile=%JOB_NAME%-%BUILD_NUMBER%.xml
> >                            if not exist artifacts\%reportfile% exit 1
> >                         '''
> >                    archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'artifacts\*.xml', fingerprint: true
> >             }
> >                 success {
> >                      println('I succeeeded!')
> >                 } 
> >                unstable {
> >                     println('I am unstable :/')
> >                }
> >                 failure {
> >                     println('I failed :(')
> >                 }
> >                 changed {
> >                     println('Things were different before...')
> >                 }
> >             }
> >         }